# How to use Transform.scale in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to use `Transform.scale` to manage sizes such as text size, icon size, etc, to make it flexible base on platform resolution such as mobile tablet or IPad. However, I do not know what is the exact scale value for mobile or ipad.

This is my code:

```
Transform.scale(
            scale: 1,  // here is the scale value
            child: Container(
              height: 1000,
              width: 500,
              color: const Color(0xFFE8581C),
              child: const Icon(
                Icons.home,
                size: 100,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

How can I adapt this to use flexible styles?

Comment: it's a bad practice to use this, I think this will help you https://medium.com/@cagdaspektas3405/flutter-responsive-ui-with-sizer-4d95235b2d3e

Answer (score 0):

Well, You have to research on what constraints define the device type.
mostly height and width are used to define what kind of device we are using. it also happens that there are some special type of devices like foldable phones  and others...

if we consider android phone google have made 3 categories of device types:
Compact(normal phones), Medium(foldable, mini tablets), Expanded (large screen tablets) as a specific values of height and width can be found out using media query and render accordingly

find more info about android layouts here [Responsive layouts by google develoeprs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ir3LztqbeRI)

a good starting point for you is to learn about responsive layouts in flutter using [media query](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html)

i will attach a good tutorial for you to get started on flutter ui responsiveness
check out

[Adaptive vs Responsive Design with flutter - flutterYT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HD5gYnspYzk)

[Responsive UI with flutter - Mitch Koko](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MrPJBAOzKTQ)